# Renaming an image file on a Mac computer including spaces and the pipe character in the file name

Tags: macos

I'm a photographer, and I use the program "PhotoMechanic" to rename files as they are copied from my memory card to my Mac computers. My convention for file names results in files that look like:

MM2_1511 | 2022-06-08.nef

MM2 refers to a specific camera.
1511 is the file number
2022-06-08 means June 8, 2022

I understand the pipe character may be a problem with Windows computers, but I've been doing this for many years on my Mac, and the suggestion came from an experienced PhotoMechanic user's video.  To make it easier for windows users who might want to open the file, before uploading to a forum I have replaced the pipe symbol with a dash, or a single letter.

After renaming the image file "MM2_1511 **x** 2022-06-08.nef" in DxO PhotoLab, my image editor, I uploaded the renamed file to a forum window, where it showed up with the original pipe symbol rather than the "x".  My friend then zipped the file, transferred the zip-file to her computer, and again, when it was un-zipped it showed the pipe symbol, not the "x" that I had renamed the file with.

After working on this for two hours yesterday, we are stuck.  Perhaps having two "space" characters and the "pipe" character in the file name are the problem - but we both use Mac, and as far as we know, this should not be a problem.

My question - how can I examine my file after renaming, to verify there are no invisible characters in the file name that are causing this problem?  I can also upload the renamed file here, if I'm allowed to do this, and if it would help solve our problem.

......none of the above sounds reasonable to me.  If I rename a file, removing the pipe symbol, all traces of the old name should be gone - I think.

Comment: I don't know of any exif field that would store the original file name. If you have [exiftool](https://exiftool.org) you could check to see if PhotoMechanic might be adding its own custom field. If you've never used it before, at it simplest once installed, in Terminal just type `exiftool [space]` then drag an image onto the Terminal window, hit Enter & read down the results. BTW, you're right that Windows can't handle a pipe | in a file name. It's an illegal character. Mac, as you've noticed, doesn't mind them at all. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31976060

Comment: Trying to do what you suggested, but "exiftool" doesn't want to open my .nef file (raw image from Nikon D750).  It will open my exported .jpg file, but that's not where the problem is.  It is something inside of the .nef file - I think.

Comment: It shouldn't have any issue with a NEF - I'm a Nikon shooter too. Try one straight from the camera. Maybe check Terminals perms in Security/Privacy CP.